# Best frontend practice for saving object to a backend before or after creation

Tags: forms, frontend, crud

**situation**: Lets's think about basic process of object creation on a client (with CRUD backend).
Let's imagine that we have two "Create" buttons on a page.

**first case**:
Clicking on the first button will cause to redirect to `/create` route, where our form located.
After we fill the form with data, we post it to a backend and it retrieves an id of a newly created object.

**second case**:
Clicking on the second button will cause to send creation request to the backend, then after we got a new object id, we will be redirected to `/edit/:id`, where our form located (same form).
After we fill the form with data, we send it to a backend and save already existed object (post by id).

**question**:
What's the pros and cons of those two cases, when to use each of them?

Comment: my first thoughts: the second case allows us to have multiple create forms with different data. it will create object before it was filled with a data. but it will cause a lot of garbage objects, that was created, but not filled.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case you can include the validation of the fields in the time of creation
and you only need to create an insert so one database call.

In the second case you are creating an empty entry that will appear in the grids of an application with no data. 
Also if your database has required fields, you have to fill them with default data. 
Validation will be more difficult since you need to allow empty ex Mobile in data entry
while phone might be required.
Another problem with this is that that you are basically doing two operations. One if for the Insert of the row and one is for the update of the row
However this methodology is easier to implement the live update of text when typing so any disconnects etc will not lose any data. This methodology is also good for collaboration between two clients using websockets ex inserting the row at the same time.